# Mocking a class with custom annotation is throwing an error - AnnotationFormatError: Attempt to create Proxy for a non-annotation type

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermockito

I am trying to mock a class that is being sent as a parameter to the constructor of the class I want to test.

Mock creation line is throwing a Java annotation error.
If I remove the annotation, the mocking is successful.

I need to know why the mocking is not possible or is there something I need to do different.

Tried with both Mockito2 and PowerMockito2. Both resulted in same error.

Code is as below

```
AnnotationClass {
 ....
 MyAnnotationClass {
  ....
 }
}

@MyAnnotationClass
MyFilterClass {
}

SUTClass {
  SUTClass(MyFilterClass filter) {
  }
}

import static org.mockito2.Mockito.*;
import static org.powermock2.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic;

import org.junit.*;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock2.core.classloader.annotations.SuppressStaticInitializationFor;
import org.powermock2.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock2.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock2.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import system.context.IUserContext;
import system.context.UserContext;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
Testclass {
  MyFilterClass filter = mock(MyFilterClass.class); //throws annotation err
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
org.mockito2.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Mockito cannot mock this class: class core.product.MyFilterClass.

Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes.
If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list.


Java               : 1.8
JVM vendor name    : Azul Systems, Inc.
JVM vendor version : 25.212-b04
JVM name           : OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
JVM version        : 1.8.0_212-b04
JVM info           : mixed mode
OS name            : Mac OS X
OS version         : 10.14.6


Underlying exception : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create type
    at core.product.TestClass.setUp(TestClass.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBefores(MethodRoadie.java:133)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:96)
    at org.powermock2.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
    at org.powermock2.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:131)
    at org.powermock2.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.access$100(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:59)
    at org.powermock2.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner$TestExecutorStatement.evaluate(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)
    at org.powermock2.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.evaluateStatement(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:107)
    at org.powermock2.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock2.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:298)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
    at org.powermock2.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:218)
    at org.powermock2.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:160)
    at org.powermock2.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:134)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock2.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:136)
    at org.powermock2.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:117)
    at org.powermock2.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:57)
    at org.powermock2.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create type
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:154)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:365)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:174)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:376)
    at org.mockito2.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.mockClass(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:32)
    at org.mockito2.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.createMockType(SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.java:71)
    at org.mockito2.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.java:42)
    at org.mockito2.internal.creation.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(ByteBuddyMockMaker.java:25)
    at org.powermock2.api.mockito.mockmaker.PowerMockMaker.createMock(PowerMockMaker.java:41)
    at org.mockito2.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:35)
    at org.mockito2.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:62)
    at org.mockito2.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1896)
    at org.powermock2.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.createMethodInvocationControl(DefaultMockCreator.java:108)
    at org.powermock2.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.doCreateMock(DefaultMockCreator.java:61)
    at org.powermock2.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.createMock(DefaultMockCreator.java:53)
    at org.powermock2.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.mock(DefaultMockCreator.java:40)
    at org.powermock2.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock(PowerMockito.java:126)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Attempt to create proxy for a non-annotation type.
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationInvocationHandler.<init>(AnnotationInvocationHandler.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser$1.run(AnnotationParser.java:306)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser$1.run(AnnotationParser.java:303)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.annotationForMap(AnnotationParser.java:303)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72)
    at java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Class.java:3521)
    at java.lang.Class.annotationData(Class.java:3510)
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotations(Class.java:3446)
    at org.mockito2.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassBytecodeGenerator.mockClass(SubclassBytecodeGenerator.java:141)
    at org.mockito2.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator$1.call(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:37)
    at org.mockito2.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator$1.call(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:34)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:152)
    ... 47 more
```

Comment: You might want to add the stacktrace and a more complete version of your UnitTest including the imports. For example which runner/extension are you using?

Comment: @second added the info you have asked for.

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]? Also what mockito/powermockito version are you using? I tried this with my own custom annotation but didn't manaeg to receive the same error.